# Rivets.js rv-show not working with rv-each

Tags: javascript, jquery, rivets.js

I am new to Rivets.js. Given this code:

```html
<div id="main">

  <div>
    <button rv-on-click="toggle">
      Toggle
    </button>
  </div>

  <div>
    Dynamic headers sould be visible: {showDynamicHeaders}
  </div>

  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Fixed header</th>
        <th>Fixed header</th>
        <th rv-show="showDynamicHeaders" rv-each-item="items">
          {item.name}
        </th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
  </table>

</div>
```

```js
var rvcontext = {};
var rview = rivets.bind($("#main"), rvcontext);  

rvcontext.showDynamicHeaders = true;

rvcontext.items = [
  {
    name : "Dynamic header 1"
  },{
    name : "Dynamic header 2"
  },{
    name : "Dynamic header 3"
  }
];

rvcontext.toggle = function(){
  rvcontext.showDynamicHeaders = !rvcontext.showDynamicHeaders;
}
```

I'd expect the table's dynamic headers to show up or not depending on the value of `showDynamicHeaders`. But it doesn't seem to work; instead, the headers are visible or not depending on the *initial* value of `showDynamicHeaders`, but their visibility doesn't change when the value is updated.

See [**this fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/_abl/r2r2ztyz/) for a live example.

I am doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try moving your `rv-show` to the `<table>` tag, like this:

```
<table rv-show="showTable" >
    <tbody>
      <tr rv-each-item="items">
        <td>{item.name}</td>
      </tr>
    <tbody>
  </table>
```

[working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cgtz8ft7/1/)

Edit: Another option would be to add a rv-class tag in the each, like this:

```
 <div rv-each-i="data" rv-class-hide="i.a | neq 1">
    {i.a} - {i.b} ({i.c})
 </div>
```

javascript:

```
var data = [
    {a:1, b:"testing1", c:true},
    {a:1, b:"testing1a", c:true},
    {a:1, b:"testing1b", c:true},
    {a:2, b:"testing2", c:false},
    {a:2, b:"testing2a", c:true},
    {a:50, b:"testing50", c:false}
];

rivets.formatters.neq = function(val, v2) { return val!=v2;};

$(document).ready(function() {
    var $r = $('#rivets');
  rivets.bind($r, {data:data});
});
```

[working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kL9v7L0e/7/) of the rv-class method

Comment: That works, but I would like to have rv-each and rv-show on the same element, because I have a case in which some `tr`s are fixed and others are dynamic. I will update the question to include this requirement.

Comment: I've had similar issues before, and have yet to get rv-show to work on the same tag as rv-each. Seems rv-show might be trying to run before the rv-each has actually attached the element to the DOM...at least I get a JS error talking about how the element's parent can't be found. My solution was to use rv-class instead, and to add a "hide" class if I don't want the row to show. Not sure if that would work for you.

Comment: That would be an acceptable workaround, but I can't get it to work. In [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/_abl/afnqufw7/) for example, the class `visible` is always present, regardless of the value of `showDynamicHeaders`. Do you have a working example?

Comment: I edited my answer to show code for working rv-class. Also I made a slight change to [your fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/afnqufw7/14/). rivets doesn't seem to like top-level properties very well. I made minimal changes to your model to get it working... but really I would recommend doing something more like `rivets.bind(element, { data: rvcontext});` I think you'll find that it gives much more consistent results.

Comment: Thanks. So it looks like the real problem comes from reassigning properties directly to the binded object (`rvcontext`).

Answer (score 0):

Although not related to your problem I found this question whilst searching for rv-show not working within an array loop - turns out the rv-show binding needs either boolean or integer values passed to it. "0" or "1" always evaluate to true, so in my case I just cast the data to an integer and it worked as intended.

Just added that in case someone else stumbles over this question with the same cause as me, especially if dealing with AJAX data.